# Diferença entre data inicial e data final com moment js

Tags: datetime, typescript, angular, momentjs

Estou precisando informar quanto tempo tenho de um certo cronometro, tenho a data do momento a qual comecei o evento.

Estou desenvolvendo com `angular 4` `typescript` e utilizo plugin [moment js](https://github.com/urish/angular2-moment)

Em meu html estou fazendo assim:

```
<div class="row card-indicator centralize-text">
  {{((locations[indiceMotorist]?.trip.createdAt == undefined)? '0' : locations[indiceMotorist]?.trip.createdAt) | amDifference: today :'minutes' : true }}
</div>
```

O restultado que é imprimido na tela está sendo:

> -62.444583333333334

Minha data está neste formato, e ela vem do meu servidor:

```
createdAt: "2017-11-01T13:13:59.015Z"
```

Um ponto importante é que não posso usar a data do meu computador devido ao horário do servidor e do pc cliente podem esta desatualizados. Para resolver este problema de tempos em tempos envio uma localização que contem uma hora também do servidor.

```
createdAt: "2017-11-01T14:22:23.466Z"
```

Estou pensando em fazer a data final (no caso a que mandei da localização) - a data inicial, com intuito de obter o tempo que está em percurso.

Não sei se consigo fazer isto com o moment js, porém preciso fazer isto, como posso conseguir ?

Existe algum plugin que facilite, ou mesmo `javascript` nativo que solucione meu problema.

Comment: Você quer realmente saber como faz essa diferença e como converte para, sei lá, horas, minutos e segundos? Ou precisa mesmo é da cronometragem? Milésimos importam?

Comment: Não milissegundos nao importa, preciso so de horas minutos e segundos,

Comment: @José conseguiu alguma coisa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Pode-se usar `Date()`** para solucionar o problema. Basta criar um novo objeto com o tempo de início (e término) desejado e fazer um novo `Date()` com a diferença. Depois, acesse horas, minutos, segundos e milissegundos separadamente com os métodos que acompanham `Date()` para formatar do jeito desejado. *Veja um exemplo*:

```js
// Usar como argumento as datas recuperadas do servidor
var inicio = new Date("2017-11-01T13:13:59.015Z");
var fim = new Date("2017-11-01T14:22:23.466Z");

// A diferença "d" de datas bruta retorna como milissegundos (inteiro)
var d = new Date( fim - inicio );

// Mostrando:
tempo =  d.getUTCHours() + "h ";
tempo += d.getUTCMinutes() + "m ";
tempo += d.getUTCSeconds() + "s ";
tempo += d.getUTCMilliseconds() + "ms";

console.log( tempo );
```

Comment: Consigo fazer isto em tempo de execução usando typescript ?

Comment: @RenanRodrigues sim.

Answer (score 2):

Existe a função `diff` do [moment](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/).

```
var antes = moment("2017-11-01T13:13:59.015Z");
var depois= moment("2017-11-01T14:22:23.466Z');

var horas = depois.diff(antes, 'hours');
var minutos = depois.diff(antes, 'minutes');
var segundos= depois.diff(antes, 'seconds');

var diferenca = `${horas}:${minutos}:${segundos}`
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rLjQx/3745/)